# C vs C++ enum linkage with extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, enums, linkage

I have a header with only an unscoped enum declared:

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_BAR_ENUM_H
#define FOO_BAR_ENUM_H

typedef enum Foo {
    Bar,
    BigBar,
    LittleBar,
    MassiveBar
    BarCount
} Foo;

#endif
```

I use this header from both C and C++. Should it be guarded by an extern "C" block? Including from both compiles fine, but is there a linking difference in this usage that is valid as far as the compiler is concerned but may not be expected from a naive user?

Comment: It's valid C and valid C++, if that's what you are asking about. You are not going to be linking with header files.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Being "valid" in both does not necessarily mean that it is the "same" in both.

Comment: For header files that are intended to work in both C and C++, always wrap them in an `extern "C"` (`#ifdef __cplusplus \n extern "C" { \n #endif`, similar to close the block at the end). That way, you never even have to ask

Comment: If you need a finer grain than at the header level, split up the headers. Any one header should either be compliant in both or not be used in both. When you find yourself thinking, "X doesn't matter, so I'm safe." think forward a few weeks, months or years to when Y is added to the header and suddenly it DOES matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This header is not going to generate any symbols for linkage, hence it is not necessary to guard it with an `extern "C"` block.

Comment: This could still cause problems if an `extern "C" enum` is mangled differently from a plain `enum` (when used in function parameters or template arguments), or if calling conventions differed for `extern "C" enum`s, etc.

Comment: @Justin It is still the function that needs to be guarded by `extern "C"`, not the enum declaration. There is no such thing as an `extern "C" enum`. It makes no difference whether the enum is declared inside or outside an `extern "C"` block.